# Call a method in Python file from AngularJS, going through parameter specific data

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

I have a project on AngularJS + Django, and I have a method in a Python file since I need some methods that use the Linux console, but some values are passed to it by parameters. That method is called from AngularJS, as I can with angualrjs call that method, passing a specific datum that I want. Thank you

Here is an example of one method in Python file that calls the shell:

```
def get_logs(nombre_contenedor):
    lista = []
    logs = subprocess.check_output("docker logs " + nombre_contenedor + " > logs.txt", shell=True)

    print 'logs',logs
    get_logs()
```

I need to call it in my view in angularjs I need to call it in my view in AngularJS, in an example like this, when you press a button (already checked that we have the variable to send), call the Python `archivito` method and pass the given variable

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm"
ng-click="ctrl.detalles()" ui-sref="recursos">
    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option2"><i
    class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Recursos Totales
</label>
```

What should I do, for example, in the controller?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. You can wrap your function in a [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) endpoint and [call it using REST/AJAX from Angular](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html). That said, as currently stated your question is too broad for this website - try to show what you have tried and the specific problems with your implementation.